# How to get the blktrace tool to show the D - issued action

Tags: blktrace

This question is about the blktrace tool. On several Ubuntu 3.16.0 machines in our lab I need to trace the software vs device block IO performance. We sometimes use our custom nvme driver and sometimes the standard one. Here is a excerpt of the blkparse output (with the standard nvme driver):

```
259,0    2   189505     9.997188463  8160  Q   R 126875648 + 248 [fio]
259,0    2   189506     9.997191290  8160  Q   R 126875896 + 8 [fio]
259,0    2   189507     9.997215574  8160  Q   R 363057152 + 248 [fio]
259,0    2   189508     9.997218444  8160  Q   R 363057400 + 8 [fio]
259,0    2   189509     9.997219210  8160  C   R 216536568 + 8 [0]
259,0    2   189510     9.997220497  8160  C   R 126875896 + 8 [0]
259,0    2   189511     9.997230160  8160  C   R 363057400 + 8 [0]
259,0    2   189512     9.997248050  8160  Q   R 147316736 + 248 [fio]
259,0    2   189513     9.997250930  8160  Q   R 147316984 + 8 [fio]
259,0    2   189514     9.997277161     0  C   R 147316984 + 8 [0]
```

This shows the Queued and Complete actions but not the D - issued actions that I am interested in. That is the problem. I need more actions (events) shown. This is from

```
blktrace /dev/nvme0n1
```

meanwhile, on other Linux machines it works, or even on the same machine if I trace a different device like

```
blktrace /dev/sda
```

That works as shown in this excerpt:

```
  8,0   18       69    17.778827207  8538  Q  RA 306186592 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       70    17.778827767  8538  G  RA 306186592 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       71    17.778828037  8538  I   R 306186592 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       72    17.778828284  8538  D   R 306186592 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       73    17.778832181  8538  A  RA 306186600 + 8 <- (8,1) 306184552
  8,0   18       74    17.778832397  8538  Q  RA 306186600 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       75    17.778832951  8538  G  RA 306186600 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       76    17.778833221  8538  I   R 306186600 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       77    17.778833441  8538  D   R 306186600 + 8 [ls]
  8,0   18       78    17.778837161  8538  A  RA 306186608 + 8 <- (8,1) 306184560
```

This last one (with /dev/sda) shows all the different actions, which is great.
So how do I get the detailed blktrace for the nvme0n1 device? And why does it not automatically show the other actions (besides Q and C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see D as long as your nvme device is has a block device interface. Try `libaio` engine in `fio` and run a `random write`. Make sure to set NOOP IO scheduler in `/sys/block/nvme../scheduler`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's working now. Upgrading Ubuntu to 15.04 may have also helped, I kind of did several changes at once.